# Correct PHP to output a single result of a Function with SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

So I have created a function on a separate php inc page and want to output the single result of the function on another page.

This is the function

```
function get_all_rating_criteria_travel5(){
    
    global $wpdb; 
    $query = "SELECT RatingCriteriaText from ratingcriteria WHERE NicheID=1 AND StarRatingID=5";
    $result = $wpdb->get_var($query);
}
```

On the page I want the result I put this

```
<?php echo get_all_rating_criteria_travel5($result->RatingCriteriaText); ?>
```

I get no errors, but no result.  I have tested the SELECT Query in PHPMyadmin and that produces exactly what I want.  Can anyone help, I've spent hours combining different variations and I cant get it to output the database result field. I'm sure its something stupid.

EDIT: I can do this on the page and it works, but how do I do this as a function

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$rating5 = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT RatingCriteriaText from ratingcriteria WHERE NicheID=1 AND StarRatingID=5;')
?>
<?php echo $rating5 ?>
```

Comment: There does not appear to be any error handling in your code, but the most important problem is that your function does not return a value. This isn't an SQL issue, it's a basic beginner PHP problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!  Amazing what a good nights sleep does!

Function:

```
function get_all_rating_criteria_travel6(){
global $wpdb;
$rating6 = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT RatingCriteriaText from ratingcriteria WHERE NicheID=1 AND StarRatingID=5;');
echo $rating6;
}
```

Code to display:

```
<?php get_all_rating_criteria_travel6(); ?>
```